# Listing usernames that are actually computers in Debian

Tags: debian-squeeze, parsing

I have inherited about 6 servers (all Debian based), and part of my project over the next year is consolidate everything into one server. There are 6 "domains" running from Samba3 installations, and I'd like to merge them all into the one new server once I get everything sorted out. What I would like is to know if there is a way to load the `/etc/passwd` file to show just usernames that end in a `$`, so I know they are a computer name. Once I can get this, I can (hopefully) make a script to add all the machines to the new master, but that's for another question later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep \$\: | cut -d : -f 1
```

would be my first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | grep '\$$'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
grep -P '^[^:]+?\$:' /etc/passwd
```

Is the most concise way to do this.

Edit: Found a more concise way. This will not confuse stray "$:" that exist in GECOS fields, for example.